# python NameError from the max fuzzy value file chosen

Tags: python

I have a script which is used to find the best file from the maximum fuzzy ratio. The file chosen will be used futher. But I get this error:

```
    with open(best_fuzzy_file,'r') as file:
NameError: name 'best_fuzzy_file' is not defined
>>>
```

Please help me to fix my code!
My code:

```
for j in cursor.fetchall():
    s1=j[0]

    def good_ratio(a):
        return fuzz.token_set_ratio(a, s1) 
    for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
        dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
        if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):

            condition_matched_in_file = False
            with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
               try:
                   my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
               except TypeError:
                   # file empty, move to next file
                   continue
               fuzzinessav=(my_sum/my_len)
               filenames2fuzz[dir_entry_path].append(fuzzinessav)
            best_fuzziness_ratio = 0  
            for k, v in filenames2fuzz.items():                       
                    if max(v) > best_fuzziness_ratio:
                        best_fuzzy_file = k                        
                        best_fuzziness_ratio = max(v)
    with open(best_fuzzy_file) as f:   #<-Gets me an error
                print best_fuzzy_file
```

Comment: 'best_fuzzy_file' should be defined to a default value e.g empty string at the first for loop and add a pre check before opening the file whether the file is existing or not. that solves your problem.

Comment: The conditions of your for loop never are true, and best_fuzzy_file is therefore not defined. True hard coding a default value

Comment: There are numerous conditions under which `best_fuzzy_file` will never get assigned; without the data, it's impossible to say which is leading to your error. You should split this code into several separate functions to you can test each in isolation.

Comment: @Anvesh ,I hope so ur idea solve my prob!Please provide me an Answer/example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
for j in cursor.fetchall():
    best_fuzzy_file = ''
    s1=j[0]

    def good_ratio(a):
        return fuzz.token_set_ratio(a, s1) 
    for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
        dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
        if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):

            condition_matched_in_file = False
            with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
               try:
                   my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
               except TypeError:
                   # file empty, move to next file
                   continue
               fuzzinessav=(my_sum/my_len)
               filenames2fuzz[dir_entry_path].append(fuzzinessav)
            best_fuzziness_ratio = 0  
            for k, v in filenames2fuzz.items():                       
                    if max(v) > best_fuzziness_ratio:
                        best_fuzzy_file = k                        
                        best_fuzziness_ratio = max(v)
    if os.path.exists(file_location+'/'+best_fuzzy_file): # can be checked using other modules
         with open(best_fuzzy_file) as f:
             print best_fuzzy_file
```

I have defined the 'best_fuzzy_file' in the begining of for loop and prechecked the file using the os module..